# Regex correctly matches everything except first match in file

Tags: regex

I'm using RegEx to extract time-marking from a text file like this:

```
> [00:00:00.1]  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
> [00:00:02.3]  Sed facilisis orci at erat vulputate facilisis.
> [00:00:08.2]  Nam aliquam velit quis nisl posuere, ut blandit turpis
> blandit. 
> [00:00:13.8]  Nulla sit amet metus felis. Nulla aliquam
> ultrices ipsum eget mattis. 
> [00:00:19.2]  Nulla porta ligula
> scelerisque lorem dapibus porttitor. 
> [00:00:26.6]  Praesent dolor mi,
> dictum et ante sed, efficitur auctor tortor. 
> [00:00:35.5]  Praesent
> euismod dui sem, 
>               vitae pretium nisi suscipit quis. 
> [00:00:39.7]  Nulla porta ligula scelerisque lorem dapibus porttitor.
```

The desired result is this:

```
00:00:00.1
00:00:02.3
00:00:08.2
00:00:13.8
00:00:19.2
00:00:26.6
00:00:35.5
00:00:39.7
```

After a lot of blood, sweat, and tears, I got this regex...

```
(?:^|])([^[\]]+)(?:\[|$)
```

...to produce this result:

```
[00:00:00.1
00:00:02.3
00:00:08.2
00:00:13.8
00:00:19.2
00:00:26.6
00:00:35.5
00:00:39.7
```

It's **almost** perfect... except for the first square bracket, right at the beginning. I'm sure it's probably something simple, but I think I'm too close to the woods to see the trees... I've being going around in circles trying to target that one bracket without undoing everything else. Can anyone point me the right way?

Comment: Which language do you use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would just capture all matches rather than matching everything you dont want and stripping it. Something like:

```
\[\K[^\]]+
```

and group `\0` should have your results.

It finds `[` then ignores that in the match because of the `\K` then captures every character until a `]`.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/1GDA9t/1/

A PHP implementation would be:

```
preg_match_all('/\[\K[^\]]+/', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/EFnGc

Comment: I feel a bit silly now... I've been look at this totally backwards: trying to remove what I don't want instead of just extracting what I do want. Thanks to everyone for the super-helpful answers; I really appreciate it. I accepted this answer because of the PHP example... that's what really helped. There are so few understandable examples 'out there' when it comes to regex. I found this most useful.

Answer (score 1):

How about this one?:

```
^>\s\[([^\]]+)\]
```

You should capture group 1. It's simpler and it gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply fish for the number block:

[`\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\.\d`](https://regex101.com/r/FWsCii/1)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just want everything between brackets, so this will work:

```
(?<=\[).+(?=])
```

fiddle: https://regex101.com/r/pRJNPG/2

`(?<=\[)` is a look-behind for a `[` character.

`.+` matches any character one or more times until the look-ahead.

`(?=])` is a look-ahead for a `]` character.

Answer (score 1):

I would use simply this one:

```
\[(.+)\]
```

And will capture the group 1.
Here is the working [**`demo`**](https://regex101.com/r/PnzjdD/1).